# Having some trouble on this Python problem

Tags: python

I'm tasked with this question:

> Design a program that asks the user to enter a store’s sales for each day of the week. The amounts should be stored in a list. Use a loop to calculate the total sales for the week and display the result.

I've written this thus far

```
listf=[0,]
def total_list(listf):
sales_total= int(input("enter weekly sales:"))

for x in range(len(listf)):
    sales_total +=listf[x]
return sales_total
```

Comment: Don't: `for x in range(len(listf)): ... listf[x] ...` Rather: `for x in listf: ... x ...`

Comment: There are two tasks here:  1) read in the sales amounts for each day and store them in a list, and 2) calculate the sum of that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the user for the entire week's sales:

```
sales_total= int(input("enter weekly sales:"))
```

but the spec says that you should be asking them for the sales for each day of the week (individually) and put them in a list:

> asks the user to enter a store’s sales for each day of the week. The amounts should be stored in a list.

That might look something like:

```
>>> sales = [int(input(f"Enter the sales for {day}: ")) for day in "SMTWTFS"]
Enter the sales for S: 0
Enter the sales for M: 4
Enter the sales for T: 5
Enter the sales for W: 3
Enter the sales for T: 5
Enter the sales for F: 9
Enter the sales for S: 1
```

Now you have all the daily sales in a list:

```
>>> sales
[0, 4, 5, 3, 5, 9, 1]
```

and you can sum them to get the weekly sales:

```
>>> sum(sales)
27
```